# Does this Map-like structure exist as part of some standard Collection?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I'm looking for a Map structure that would behave like this

```
public MapBiggest<K,V implements Comparable> extends Map<K,V implements Comparable>{

  @override  
  public V put(K key, V value){
    T currentValue = null;
                                                 // Insert in one of two cases
    if((currentValue = this.get(key)) == null || // case1: key isn't in map
      value.compareTo(currentValue)>0){          // case2: new value is > currentValue
      return super.put(key,value);
    }
    return currentValue;
  }
}
```

That is, you could keep inserting items and there would be some logic (`Comparator`) that decides which elements are kept.

Thanks.

(Note, none of this code has been compiled)

Edit #1: Put returns `V`

Comment: No, there's no such kind of `Map`.

Comment: No, but you could easily create a class that wraps a Map

Comment: Also, put does not return void

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public MapBiggest<K, V implements Comparable> {

  final Map<K, V,> backingMap //in the constructor you say new HashMap<>();

  public V put(K key, V value){
    final V currentValue = backingMap.get(key);
    if(currentValue == null || currentValue.compareTo(value) < 0) { 
        return backingMap.put(key, value);
    }        
    return currentValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget the `implements Map<K,V>` part ?

Comment: No, I am not implementing a Map, I am wrapping around it

Comment: First line of code in OP question : `public MapBiggest<K,V implements Comparable> extends Map<K,V implements Comparable>`. It is written extends but an interface can only be implemented. But I think it is part of the question ...

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, this would probably just be

```
map.merge(key, value, (left, right) -> left.compare(right) > 0 ? left : right);
```